# How can I click a javascript button in a webbrowser that the code to does not show up to in the webpage source?

Tags: vb.net

Visit this site:
https://satoshimines.com/

Click play, place a bet of 0 and click play

---

Now here's what I find interesting, if you view the source of the page there's no code shown for the Game Board. I think one of the JavaScripts its calling upon is the board game. In inspect element you can see the elements for the board game
http://prntscr.com/78ge73

So, my question is it possible to click one of the game tiles if the site is loaded in a webbrowser inside VB? If so, please point me in the right direction.

Here's how I tried to click it. (Doesn't work.)

```
Private Sub Clicktile()
    TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text + "Trying to click Tile..." + Environment.NewLine
    'Try statement so if it dicks up the program won't crash
    Try
        'Declares in Memory the page source as a HtmlElementCollection
        Dim ae As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All
        'Declares in Memory each Element within the page source
        For Each wpe As HtmlElement In ae

            If wpe.GetAttribute("data-tile") = "1" Then
                wpe.InvokeMember("click")
            Else
                TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text + "Error on ClickTile1" + Environment.NewLine
            End If

        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
       TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text + "Catch ex As Exception called" + Environment.NewLine
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Ahhhhh! You're trying to cheat! (or trying to SPAM)

When you click on tile, webpage send XMLHTTPRequest to get answer status. So you can't see what is under button before you click it!

Comment: I'm trying to make a bot to play the game for me. ^_^ Thanks for the info!